# error with persisted sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I persisted a TfidfVectorizer using the module joblib. The object that I run through the method fit_transform was a list of strings.
The resulting matrix had a dimensionality of 263744 columns.

I am running a list of strings through the transform method, and I get the following error.

Any clues?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-      packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", 
line 1334, in transform
return self._tfidf.transform(X, copy=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", 
line 1037, in transform
X = X * self._idf_diag

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line    
318, in __mul__
return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py",
line 487, in _mul_sparse_matrix
other = self.__class__(other)  # convert to this format
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py",
line 31, in __init__
arg1 = arg1.asformat(self.format)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", 
line 219, in asformat
return getattr(self,'to' + format)()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/dia.py", 
line 241, in tocsr
return self.tocoo().tocsr()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/dia.py", 
line 249, in tocoo

num_offsets, offset_len = self.data.shape
AttributeError: 'NDArrayWrapper' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are persisting the trained transformer or pipeline to disk, and then reloading it before seeing the error, you could:

1. Try saving the original (working) object using the **compress** keyword argument parameter to `joblib.dump`, with an integer value greater than 0:

   ```
   _ = joblib.dump(python_object, persisted_file_name, compress=3)
   ```
2. If the persisted file is being moved to a new location, make
   sure to copy *all* the file pieces.  If it is large, joblib will
   split it up, e.g.:

   ```
   persisted_model.joblib.pkl
   persisted_model.joblib.pkl_01.npy
   persisted_model.joblib.pkl_02.npy
   ```

[joblib docs](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html)